# How to insert selected multiple checkbox values into sql server database using prepared statement?

Tags: html, servlets, jdbc

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Welcome</title>
</head>
<body>
<form  action="First_prgm" method="post">  
 <table>
<tr>
 <td> <b>3)Not including yourself, how many adults and children live in the same home as you on a permanent basis?</b></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="children" value="adults"> Adults (aged 18 and over) <br>
<input type="checkbox" name="children" value="0-4 years">Children-aged 0-4 years / house mates <br>
<input type="checkbox" name="children" value="5-8 years">Children-aged 5-8 years <br>
<input type="checkbox" name="children" value="9-11 years"> Children-aged 9-11 years <br>
<input type="checkbox" name="children" value="12-15 years"> Children-aged 12-15 years <br>
<input type="checkbox" name="children" value="16-17 years">Children-aged 16-17 years<br><br></td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
```

First_prgm.java:

```
public  class First_prgm extends HttpServlet {

public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response)
                throws IOException {
            response.setContentType("text/html");
            PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
            String insertTableSQL = "INSERT INTO MembersQnariesData"
                    + "(MemberID,FirstName,LastName,AgrGroup,AgeBrackets,LivingArrangement,DateOfBirth) VALUES"
                    + "(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";


            int id = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("mid"));
            String fname = request.getParameter("first");
            String lname=request.getParameter("last");
            String a[] =request.getParameterValues("children");
            String age_brackets = request.getParameter("age");
            String living_arngmt  = request.getParameter("member");


           String dob = request.getParameter("DOB");




            try {

                  Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
                Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://server;databaseName","username","password");

                PreparedStatement ps = con
                        .prepareStatement(insertTableSQL);

                ps.setInt(1,id);
                ps.setString(2,fname);
                ps.setString(3,lname);
                for(int j=0; j <a.length; j++){
                     ps.setString(4,a[j]);
                     out.println("selected values are"+a[j]);
                     }
                 ps.setString(5,age_brackets);
                 ps.setString(6, living_arngmt);
                 ps.setString(7,dob);

                int i = ps.executeUpdate();
                if(i>0){
                   out.println(i+ "row inserted");
                }        
            }
            catch (Exception e2) {
                e2.printStackTrace();
            }

            out.close();
        }
```

---

Can any one help me in this.Am a beginner.I have created one web application with check boxes. When the user selecting the values the latest value is inserting into the database.I need to insert selected values into different columns of a database.How to do this one

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This below code is the problem ,

```
for(int j=0; j <a.length; j++){
                     ps.setString(4,a[j]);
                     out.println("selected values are"+a[j]);
  }
```

you have fixed counter value to - 4 and that is why you are getting only last value.

Since you  don't know number of check boxes in advance, you need to construct your query dynamically using `StringBuilder` and append `a.length` questions marks in the query in the end.

Then while setting values in `PreparedStatement` , you need to take an `int counter` and increment it after setting value.

```
ps.setInt(1,id);
            ps.setString(2,fname);
            ps.setString(3,lname);
             ps.setString(4,age_brackets);
             ps.setString(5, living_arngmt);
             ps.setString(6,dob);
int counter = 7; //since six question marks are already added for other fields
for(int j=0; j <a.length; j++){
                         ps.setString(counter++,a[j]);
                         out.println("selected values at index : "+j+" is : "+a[j]);
      }
```

or you can initialize `counter = 1` and start from beginning like ,

```
int counter = 1;
ps.setInt(counter++,id);
                ps.setString(counter++,fname);
                ps.setString(counter++,lname);
                 ps.setString(counter++,age_brackets);
                 ps.setString(counter++, living_arngmt);
                 ps.setString(counter++,dob);
    ; //since six question marks are already added for other fields
    for(int j=0; j <a.length; j++){
                             ps.setString(counter++,a[j]);
                             out.println("selected values at index : "+j+" is : "+a[j]);
          }
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply,It is solved by myself by adding the below code.             for(int i=0;i<checkValues.length;++i)
             {
               value+=checkValues[i]+",";
     

             }
             
              ps.setString(4, value);

Comment: Now Am getting null pointer exception when am not inserting any values int agrgroup coloumn how to handle this?

Comment: `AgrGroup` column should have all the selected values ( single row in DB ) or want to have multiple rows - one for each agegroup?

Comment: Actually my requirement is when user select question 2 options based on choosen option the next question have to display.                                       For example que2 has 2 options A and B .When user selects option A the que 3 has to display and for oprion B que 4 has to display.When the que 3 is skipping the value is not inserting into the database and nullpointerexception is raising.

Comment: I am not able to understand your question so can't help. All these issues are very easy to fix provided you have basics right.